# WebClient always returns org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I'm just new to Webclient and trying it locally.

I'm encountering this error as I try to hit the endpoint I made,

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=MonoResponseDto
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$readWithMessageReaders$12(BodyExtractors.java:201) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://localhost:7000/v2/consent [DefaultClientResponse]
```

Here is my code for hitting the endpoint

```
            String url = "http://localhost:7000/v2/consent";
            Mono<MonoResponseDto> response = webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(url)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(MonoResponseDto.class);
```

I also tried changing the Object to String

```
                    Mono<String> response = webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(url)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Response

```
2023-02-06 10:27:20.342  INFO 99607 --- [nio-8012-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
{"result":"SUCCESS","data":{"createdAt":"2022-03-03T09:19:49.248Z","updatedAt":"2022-03-03T09:19:49.248Z","id":2058,"type":"Data Privacy","version":"1.3","value":"Test privacy"}}
```

and it worked like a charm.

Here is my code for controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v2/consent")
public class ConsentController {

    @Autowired
    private ConsentService consentService;

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Consent> getConsent(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(consentService.getConsent(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I think the `.accept()` is not enough to change the contentType of my request.
Please advise what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Note: This only happens on my machine. Tried pulling other codes from other repositories with the same implementation and it still encounters the same error.

Comment: add Controller code here

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your controller.

You should add content type wich you producing

```
@GetMapping(path = "/v2/consent", consumes = "*/*", produces = "application/json")
```

Comment: hi @ShakirovRamil, already edited my post with controller code. tried this one also and it still encounters the same error. wonder why this only doesn't work on my machine and it works on my colleagues machine. btw I'm using IntelliJ and Java11.

Comment: after more debugging, turns out that I did not add the headers with `Content-Type` on my mock response. this is now working fine. thanks for the advise @Shakirov!